# Debugging the error in simulink model

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am trying to work with Simulink using Cyfuzz which generates random models to test the simulink compiler for any bugs. I have generated a random model which can be found at:

[sampleModel Link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1s8cLg-Ms04cUtNcEM2ck5WaFE)

I have been able to debug the error manually by making some changes in the parameters of the blocks. But I want to write a function which upon encountering the error listed will make the same changes that I made. Since I am new to MATLAB, I have been struggling to do so. The changes that I made were:

1. In counter free running block (bl96), changing the sample time from -1 to 1.
2. In the integrator block (bl68), changing the initial condition from 0 to 1.

Here is the link to the corrected model:

[sampleModel Corrected](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1s8cLg-Ms04ZUNuOGQ3bUctaXM)

Any help will be really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: So, do you want ways to do the steps 1. and 2. for you from a function or script? If that is the case have you tried set_param?

Comment: @Navan I want to do that using a function.

Comment: You can do that using set_param function call. It takes a block path, name of param and value as an argument. e.g. set_param(blk_path, 'SampleTime', '1');